# My consecutive day counter reset after a few hours

Tags: support

I have been visiting the site everyday for three weeks. Tonight, after only being off the site for a few hours, it reset to 1 from 21 days here and from 20 to 1 on Movies & TV. This has happened before. GMT can't be a factor as it was only a few hours during the same night. It's making it literally impossible to earn the 100 day gold badge.

Can some mod check on this and explain the problem? I'd really like this badge and it is rather upsetting to have my efforts dashed. It's impossible I was away longer than 24 hours as I'm visiting my parent's house right now and have not even been here 12 hours.

**EDIT :** In case it's unclear, I'm talking about the **main site** here. This is not a question for the main site, it's off topic, so I brought it here. I thought it was obvious, but I may have been wrong.

Comment: Did you *do* anything on the site (vote, post, comment) on GMT Sunday, or just visit a single page? It may be that the system didn't recognise you as appearing on the site because you weren't there for long enough and didn't do anything that was logged. That said, I'm not entirely sure what triggers having "visited the site" - I'll try to look into it.

Comment: I don't think I did anything, other than load the site after logging onto my parent's wifi (which I only did at the time to maintain the day count while ignoring the family, rudely, when I got there). Then, when I had more time later, noticed the reset. It seems that logging on (thus having your page refreshed, etc) should register as visiting. If not, why call it "visiting" instead of something more active and informative? I had planned on doing more when I had time, but the reset just crushed my enjoyment.

Comment: FYI, a similar question [has been asked before](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/7016/every-time-i-get-to-somewhere-between-15-and-20-consecutive-days-it-resets-my-co), and answered by a then moderator. I'm sorry this has upset you, but there doesn't seem to be much we can do about it :-( Also, I was wrong about needing to actually *do* something - just visiting does apparently count, per [this question on another site](http://meta.webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/376/whats-the-deal-with-the-enthusiast-badge) (unless the rules have changed since then).

Comment: Looking at your [all actions tab](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/users/16974/meat-trademark?tab=activity) it appears you do have some gaps. Sorry that we can't do much about that!

Comment: If I had gaps, why was my counter at 21 days? I accept that I'm not getting my days back, but that actions tab does not register page views, ie: visits, or clicking the review link. *Which seems to make it a worthless gauge for this situation.*

Comment: It’s possible that moderators see more on that tab (though I’m not sure).

Comment: I'd hope so, but it doesn't help to point me in that direction then. And if they see more, they should *see more* and see I was there everyday. Also, it didn't help that the link in Ancient's comment was to my activity in Meta (which scores differently) when I'm referring to the main site. Like I said, I accept I'm not getting the days back, but I still feel kinda shafted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As explained in [this MSE question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66482/consecutive-days-problem-97), it is not enough to just visit the main page or log in; this alone will not make the day count against the number of days visited required for the Enthusiast and Fanatic badges. It should be sufficient to look at any question page, though.